# Comparing time from MS Access database with current system time using Visual Basic 2008

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, time

I want to get a time value from my database and compare it with the current system time. I am doing this because I want to compare if fifteen minutes have already passed after the time in the database. I am using Visual Basic 2008 and MS Access.

Specifically, this will serve as a part of an attendance checker, if a professor failed to log-in fifteen minutes after his/her scheduled start of class, a message will appear on the screen saying that he/she failed to log-in. We really need a code to get the schedule of the professor from the database.

The name of the database is DatabaseTest and the name of the field where the date/time is stored is named DT.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why don’t you use built-in functionality of Access? You can use [tag:access-vba]. Also it is possible to write a query that selects all records with time at most 15 minutes old using `NOW()`, see [Access help on current date and time manipulation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-current-date-and-time-in-calculations-HP001098479.aspx). Also, what have you tried to solve your problem? What code have you written yet?

Comment: Also related support article on functions for queries: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210604/en-us